# How to one-hot encode a table column in DolphinDB?

Tags: pivot-table, one-hot-encoding, dolphindb

I’d like to perform one-hot encoding on the `industryCode` column and preserve all other columns in the following table.

```
t = table(2022.08.01 2022.08.02 2022.08.03 as date, 000001.SZ000002.SZ000003.SZ as windCode, 110111021103 as industryCode)
```

[image]

After the conversion, the table should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requests, there are two ways to solve this.

The table:

```
t = table(2022.08.01 2022.08.02 2022.08.03 as date, `000001.SZ`000002.SZ`000003.SZ as windCode, `1101`1102`1103 as industryCode)
```

Solution #1:

**Use built-in function oneHot(obj, encodingColumns)**

```
oneHot(t, ['industryCode'])
```

[image]

Worth mentioning, with the method above, you can one hot encode multiple columns all at once.

```
oneHot(t, ['industryCode','windCode'])
```

[image]

Solution #2:

**Use SQL query**

```
res = select iif(isNull(industryCode), 0, 1) from t pivot by date, windCode, industryCode;
nullFill!(res, 0);
```

[image]

I’d recommend solution #1 for its much simpler implementation, yet supporting multiple columns.